# How to tell Google only crawl direct links?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, links

I have some links that want to Google index it so I put those links in a separate simple HTML file, updated my sitemap to Google know about this page and just link my desired pages on that now I want to Google just index direct links, not page itself how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

On the "separate simple HTML file" you created, add the following to the `<head>`

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

That will instruct Google and other search engines who respect the directive to not index that specific page but will follow the links on that page.

If you really are only interested in Google's index, then use

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Indexing and crawling is a surprisingly complex subject, and if you want to learn more, I quoted the above information directly from a [Google help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en), so you may want to start there.

Comment: thanx mate exactly what I looking for